# HTML/CSS - How to align multiple images irregular

Tags: html, css, image, alignment

What would be the best way to to achieve this design with images - each placed inside a  to include captions. And yes, it should be responsive... Somehow with grid perhaps?

[image]

I tried with float left/right (which I hate though and it gets complicated)

[Some more characters ...]

Answer (score 0):

The best option would be using Flexbox, here´s an example of what you are trying to get:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.content {
  margin: 10px;
}

.content img {
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <img width="40" />
    <span>Caption</span>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <img width="200" />
    <span>Caption</span>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <img width="70" />
    <span>Caption</span>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <img width="400" />
    <span>Caption</span>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <img width="350" />
    <span>Caption</span>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <img width="40" />
    <span>Caption</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can read more about flexbox here: [Basic concepts of flexbox - CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_flexible_box_layout/Basic_concepts_of_flexbox)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the the ideal method would be using grid. This codepen maybe what you are looking for:

[Irreguler Image Gallery](https://codepen.io/marcobiedermann/embed/ExmOLQM?)

However, you can also use flexbox but at the end you have to set width and height for each image and use margins to move them irregularly.

```
.gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  row-gap: 12em;
  column-gap: 2em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I prefer the grid to flex. So I actually do the positioning with defining the columns for every div/img.